# How do I combine @Asynchronous and Weld/CDI Events and @Observes(during=TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMPLETION) in Glassfish 3.1

Tags: events, asynchronous, jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld

First of all let me state, that the following code example worked just fine in GF 3.0.1. The troubles started when we switched to GF 3.1.

I'm using a method

```
@Asynchronous
public void executeFlowStep(
    @Observes(during=TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMPLETION) 
    ExecuteFlowStepEvent executeFlowStepEvent) {
```

Since the switch, whenever this should receive an `ExecuteFlowStepEvent` I get the following error message:

```
WELD-000401 Failure while notifying an observer of event [package].ExecuteFlowStepEvent
```

No further information or stacktrace is given.
It works if I remove the `@Asynchronous` annotation and the `AFTER_COMPLETION` attribute, of course this breaks the program as I depend on the `AFTER_COMPLETION` timing.

I tried to ask for help on the Weld Forums, so far to no avail, although there seem to be other people with the same problem: http://seamframework.org/Community/WeldUsers

I at least would like to know:
Is this a bug, or is this wanted. Does this imply that Weld does NOT work with Asynchronous methods/AFTER_COMPLETION attributes? Why did this work in GF 3.0.1?
Has anyone managed to make this work on GF 3.1?

Comment: might be a bug. try reporting it.

Comment: Posted it also at the Seam/Weld forums, no one seems to be interested there so I submitted it to the Glassfish Bugtracker a week ago, we'll see if anything comes out of that. If anyone has similar issues, this is the URL to the tracker: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16513

Comment: I would report it directly to Weld. Glashfish uses Weld as its CDI implementation.

Comment: Kind of was a couple of years since this thread was alive. Anyone know if this problem linger still in GlassFish 4?

Comment: Just found out reading the jira-link Michael posted that this was indeed a bug that was fixed in Wield 1.1.2 and GlassFish 3.2.1 (build 14+).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [link](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16513) you posted as a comment to your own question, this is a bug that was fixed in Wield 1.1.2 and GlassFish 3.1.2 (build 14+).

*disclamer*: I posted this answer to an age old question to help SO (StackOverflow) get rid of unanswered questions.