# JBOSS Asynchronus transactional method call AFTER_COMPLETION event - WELD-000401

Tags: jakarta-ee, asynchronous, jboss, cdi, weld

I call asynchronus transactional method and observe transaction commit event. Method ends sucessfuly, but instead of execution onTransactionCommit method i receive:

```
WELD-000401 Failure while notifying an observer of event
```

JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final)

Hire is my code template:

```
public class WeldExceptionProblemTest {
    @Asynchronous
    public void asynchMethod() {
    }
    public void onTransactionCommit(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMPLETION) TestEvent event) {
    }
    private class TestEvent {
    }
}
```

Comment: [I found very similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832775/how-do-i-combine-asynchronous-and-weld-cdi-events-and-observesduring-transact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use try...catch(RuntimeException) block inside asynchMethod. I had an exception there.